# Getting NPR headlines using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to get print NPR headlines from https://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/archive, but my code is not working. I am using Python3 and Selenium ChromeDriver. Here is what I have now:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


custom_path = "/Users/ashkij/Desktop/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/ashkij/Desktop/chromedriver")


#Open a page that has a list of NPR headlines.
driver.get("https://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/archive")
#After the first few articles, one has to scroll to the bottom of the page 

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

for i in range(1,10):
    #Get each article from an XPATH expression
    article_headline = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="infinitescroll"]/article[{}]/div[2]/h2/a""".format(i))
    print(article_headline.text)
```

On the first article, I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: 
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*
[@id="infinitescroll"]/article[1]/div[2]/h2/a"}
```

However, I verified that the above IS an XPath expression for a given article, so I don't know why Selenium says the XPath expression is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try on the following code:

```
headlines = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".title>a")

for headline in headlines:

    print(headline.text)
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: This works for the first few articles. But then there is this divider that says: 

`homepage news arts & life music programs about`

And all the articles after that are not found by this css_selector expression. The CSS selector for these articles is:
`#infinitescroll > article:nth-child(i) > div.item-info > h2 > a`, where `i` is the article index. How would I do something similar to the above for those articles?

Comment: @thewhitetie, my code actual for your link provided in the code. For doing the same with `news`, you should open the "news" page before. So if my answer was helpful -- check a tick near my answer, please.